# How to get MATLAB to display the row index of the minimum value in every column of a matrix?

Tags: matlab, find, row

I have am matrix like this:

S =

```
2.2100   16.0100
0.0100    9.8100
9.4100    0.0100
```

Now I want to know the row number of the minimum value in every column.
The vector I'm looking for should look like that:

D =

```
 2
 3
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[val, ind] = min (S)
```

and you will have the value:

```
val =

   0.010000   0.010000

ind =

   2   3
```